# multiple dates against count

Tags: sql

I have 3 columns

- Order_ID
- Activation_Date
- Order_Received_Date

So, if i distinctly count all the order_IDs on Order_Received_Date, I will get "Number of Orders" Similarly, if i distinctly count all the order_IDs on Activation_Date, I will get "Number of Activations"

What i want is two columns called "# Orders" and "# Activations"

Appreciate any inputs, thanks

Comment: An is your current query is _classified_?

Answer (score 1):

I use `union all` for this type of calculation.  The following is standard SQL so it should work in any database:

```
select thedate, sum(r) as numorders, sum(a) as numactivations
from (select activation_date as thedate, 1 as a, 0 as r from table t
      union all
      select order_received_date, 0, 1 from table t
     ) t
group by thedate
order by thedate;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I guess the below query might help you solve this issue:

```
SELECT 
    OrderID,
    ActivationDate,
    OrderReceivedDate,
    COUNT(OrderID) OVER (),
    COUNT(ActivationDate) OVER ()
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS OrderID, '2014-01-01' AS ActivationDate, '2013-12-15' AS OrderReceivedDate UNION
    SELECT 2 AS OrderID, NULL AS ActivationDate, '2013-12-19' AS OrderReceivedDate UNION
    SELECT 3 AS OrderID, '2014-03-01' AS ActivationDate, '2013-12-17' AS OrderReceivedDate UNION
    SELECT 4 AS OrderID, '2014-04-01' AS ActivationDate, '2013-12-03' AS OrderReceivedDate
) t
```

I wish this helps you...